# Admin panel sidebar links doesn't work in production mode

Tags: adminhtml, magento2.4, admin-panel, admin-controller

I have an issue while i switch my magento website in production mode,

The website is finally ready to be set but now i face a problem after i've installed many modules and packages, i don't know why when i'm in production mode, the admin is not working correctly and i can't access to the admin sidebar features...

So i can only access to the dashboard but i can't interact with anything...

If anyone have encountered the same problem in the past and resolved it, i'm listening to you

Thanks.

Comment: F12 in the navigator and check console errors, please post here so we can figure out what's going on

Comment: Hey i added it in response of my first post

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here is the result of the console you asked
thank you